# Working example of Spring OAuth2.0 and JWT in Java with xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am currently working on a project where I have to implement an Authorization server (java web application) which has to support JSON web token. I would very much like to use the spring support (**spring-security-oauth2**, **spring-security-jwt**) but unfortunately I can't find any example on the net.

If anyone has already implemented it I would very much appreciate if you shared this with me.

I have already looked into cloudfoundry(https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa) but can't find any help there.

Thanks.

Comment: Here Here! I have been looking for something similar and the examples are not exactly forthcoming.

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt